# Getting the max index value for each group within a list

Tags: python, list

I've been trying to figure out the most elegant way to find what the maximum index is for a particular ID within a list. The idea is that within the data I'm receiving sometimes I will get a duplicate ID. I've been told to take the most recent ID value as this is the most up to date within the list.

I've managed to implement this using Pandas which is great but I feel like there must be a better way without having to use Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

list = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C']
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': list})
df['idx'] = df.index
df = df.groupby('id').agg({'idx':'max'})
df = df.reset_index()['idx'].to_list()

print(df)
```

I was thinking perhaps I could do a lead/lag type function which would look at the previous ID value and if the current ID doesn't match the previous value then store the index of the previous ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple comprehension here:

```
lst = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C']
{j: i for i,j in enumerate(lst)}
```

gives:

```
{'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 4}
```

NB: but please, **never** use `list` as a variable name, because it hides the builtin `list` functions...

Comment: Random question thats been bugging me. Why does the comprehension default to the highest index value?

i.e 'C': 4 instead of 'C': 3

Comment: @RyanDavies: It writes the values in sequence into the dict. So it first writes `C: 3` and later `C: 4`. And the last written value wins...

Answer (score 2):

```
def maxIndex(l):
    rDict=dict()
    for x in range(len(l)):
        rDict[l[x]]=x
    return rDict
```

This will take in a list, and output a dictionary, where key is the entry, and value is the greatest index it appeared.

You can query the dictionary to get the largest index.

Output of maxIndex(list):

```
{'A': 1, 'C': 4, 'B': 2}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
max_index = {}
data = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C'] # don't use name "list" for variables
for i, e in enumerate(data):
    max_index[e] = i
print(max_index)
```

Output:

```
{'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 4}
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding to other solutions:

```
>>> lst = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C']
>>> dict(map(reversed, enumerate(lst)))
{'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 4}
```

Which uses maps the `reversed` function to each `enumerate` object with `map`, resulting in a `{element: idx}` dictionary.